# PhoneGap App Load Enternal Browser on Page load

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating a simple wrapper with the PHonegap build service for a droid that will will show the flash, then launch into the mobile version of the site.

I've tried various combinations and so far the following works the best:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<title>My App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
<script src="childbrowser.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dsl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/js/xui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function init(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function externalLoad() 
{ 
window.location.href = "http://myapp.com"; //works
}

function locationChanged(newurl) {
console.log("The JS got this url = " + newurl);
}

function closed() {
console.log("The JS got a close event");
}
function showPage(locbar) {
window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = locationChanged;
window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = closed;
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://myapp.com", {
showLocationBar: locbar
});
}
 function openExternal() {
 window.plugins.childBrowser.openExternal("http://myapp.com");
}

</script>       

</head>
<body onLoad="externalLoad();">
<button onClick="externalLoad() ;">Load Deals</button> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

The above works great except it opens the app in the app web view and I don't have access to the device browser cookies which I need.

I've tried using the childbrowser plugin and it works great but I was unable to get it to launch when the page was loaded. If the link is clicked, it works perfect.

I must be missing something because this seems like it should be fairly easy to do.

Any advice or help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "native" versus "real" cookies may be implemented differently.  A workaround would be to open a special page, with the cookie value in the parameter.  That set the cookie in the real browser and redirects to the homepage (or wherever needed).  It's a bit of work, but it is guaranteed to work in all conditions.